# Marketing Problem with intersection of percentages

Tags: percentages

I am revising some A Level maths and I am struggling a bit with the following question...

You are a manufacturer of electronics and a marketing agency has collected the following data for you:

80% of your customers own a computer

70% own a DVD Player

and 40% own both

Should you pay the invoice from this agency?

I think the answer lies in some sort of Venn Diagram

Comment: You are asking if we should pay that marketing agency for the amount of valuable data they've given?? What is the (math) question?

Comment: That is the exact wording of the question which I find is a bit abrupt

Comment: I think they want me to say if it is possible that 40 per cent own both or is the data obviously wrong, I really dont like the wording

Answer (score 0):

It's clearly impossible that only 40% of customers own both, as 70-(100%-80%)=50% forcing a minimum 50% of customers into the overlap. The math tells you they screwed up.